# How to transfer my domain from bluehost, enable email notification and receive emails?

Tags: laravel, hover, mailgun

This is sort of planning question . I have my domain at bluehost.com. But since I started to learn laravel and I am currently having temp domain in hover and I have forge/digitalocean solution.. Now I want to pull my real domain and make some email inboxes for my team.. how can I achieve that.. what tools I need to use.. my question has three parts :

1- How to pull my old domain from bluehost to forge/digitalocea, ? 2- How to create email for my team such as support@mydomain.com .. admin@mydomain.com and I want to get emails from outside world 3- How can I send email notifications from my project such as ,, account confirmation.. etc? ( I tried mailgun but it seems it not stable. it failed sometimes to send and sometimes there is delay ).

Please advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How to pull my old domain from bluehost to forge/digitalocean?

   Please refer on this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

   Or see an example here: http://bivori.com/migration-form-bluehost-to-digitalocean/
2. How to create an email server?

   You can use and integrate Zoho Mail Server for Free upto 25 users.
   Just follow this link:

   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-zoho-mail-with-a-custom-domain-managed-by-digitalocean-dns
3. How can I process email messaging?

   If your using Laravel, I suggest you follow instructions as stated in their manual:

   https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail